# ASP.NET WebForms RequiredFieldValidator with Repeater

Tags: asp.net

I have a repeater control that has textboxes and buttons for delete/update. Also in my form I have the same looking row as the repeater but this is for new records that the user can fill out. One of the fields is required so I have a RequiredFieldValidator on it. However, because they are all in the same form (because this visually looks correct), I can't update one of the records in the repeater row because the RequiredFieldValidator in the add row won't be filled out, which is fine in this case because they want to alter a different record not add a record.

So how would I be able to use the RequiredFieldValidator to require this field but only when the Add button is clicked and to ignore it if the delete or update button inside the repeater control is pressed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set CausesValidation on your delete and update buttons to false.

```
<asp:Button ID="delete" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" Text="Delete" />
```

Comment: Almost everything. ;)